# How to update into database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, windows-forms-designer

I know this question have been asked before but I still do not get the answer on why my code is not update into database. This code have no error but it not update changes data into database. Anyone please help me. Here is my code:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        bool exists2;
         using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from [m_emp_photo] where empno=@empno", con))
            {
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empno", textBoxEmpNo.Text);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", textBoxImgPath.Text);
                exists2 = (int)cmd2.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
            }

         if (exists2)
         {
             string query2 = "";
             //query2 = "update m_emp_photo set path=@path where empno=@empno";

             query2 = "UPDATE m_emp_photo set path=@path where empno=@empno";

             SqlCommand cmd2;
             cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, con);

             cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", textBoxImgPath.Text);
             MessageBox.Show("Changes has been saved!");
         }

         else
         {
             MessageBox.Show("No record found");
         }
         con.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first cmd2 don't need add `@path` parameter.
The second cmd2 you have to add `@empno` parameter and run `ExecuteNonQuery`.
I hope it will work for you.

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    bool exists2;
    using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from [m_emp_photo] where empno=@empno", con))
    {
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empno", textBoxEmpNo.Text);
        //cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", textBoxImgPath.Text);
        exists2 = (int)cmd2.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
    }

    if (exists2)
    {
        string query2 = "";
        //query2 = "update m_emp_photo set path=@path where empno=@empno";

        query2 = "UPDATE m_emp_photo set path=@path where empno=@empno";

        SqlCommand cmd2;
        cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, con);

        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empno", textBoxEmpNo.Text);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", textBoxImgPath.Text);

        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("Changes has been saved!");
    }

    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No record found");
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to execute the update:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        bool exists2;
         using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from [m_emp_photo] where empno=@empno", con))
            {
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empno", textBoxEmpNo.Text);
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", textBoxImgPath.Text);
                exists2 = (int)cmd2.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
            }

         if (exists2)
         {
             string query2 = "";
             //query2 = "update m_emp_photo set path=@path where empno=@empno";

             query2 = "UPDATE m_emp_photo set path=@path where empno=@empno";

             SqlCommand cmd2;
             cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, con);

             cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", textBoxImgPath.Text);
             cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
             MessageBox.Show("Changes has been saved!");
         }

         else
         {
             MessageBox.Show("No record found");
         }
         con.Close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess you missed to execute your SQLCommand in If statement 
use `cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();`

```
    private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            bool exists2;
             using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from [m_emp_photo] where empno=@empno", con))
                {
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empno", textBoxEmpNo.Text);                    
                    exists2 = (int)cmd2.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
                }

             if (exists2)
             {
                 string query2 = "";
                 //query2 = "update m_emp_photo set path=@path where empno=@empno";

                 query2 = "UPDATE m_emp_photo set path=@path where empno=@empno";

                 SqlCommand cmd2;
                 cmd2 = new SqlCommand(query2, con);

                 cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", textBoxImgPath.Text);
                 cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empno", textBoxEmpNo.Text);

                 cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 MessageBox.Show("Changes has been saved!");
             }

             else
             {
                 MessageBox.Show("No record found");
             }
             con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: technically it is not a query, thats why you use `ExecuteNonQuery` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code.

First, you didn't execute the update. Add this line:

```
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Second, your first command doesn't have `@path` parameter, so why are you adding it?

Third, you constructed a new command, so you lost the parameters. You have to add the `@empno` parameter again just like you did with the `@path`:

```
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empno", textBoxEmpNo.Text);
```

Fourth, since you constructed a new command, you need another `using` statement.

Your code should be something like this:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        bool exists2;
         using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from [m_emp_photo] where empno=@empno", con))
            {
                cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empno", textBoxEmpNo.Text);
                exists2 = (int)cmd2.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
            }

         if (exists2)
         {
             using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE m_emp_photo set path=@path where empno=@empno", con))
             {
                 cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empno", textBoxEmpNo.Text);
                 cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@path", textBoxImgPath.Text);
                 cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 MessageBox.Show("Changes has been saved!");
             }
         }
         else
         {
             MessageBox.Show("No record found");
         }
         con.Close();
    }
```

One last thing. I don't know what database you're using, but the `update` statement in almost all databases returns the number of updated rows. You can use that as a feedback whether your update statement succeeded or not. Something like this:

```
if(cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Changes has been saved!");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Failed to save changes!");
}
```

However, this is not enough, and it is highly recommended to wrap your entire code in a `try...catch` statement and display friendly errors.